# How to find the expectation value of $P^2$ for the hydrogen atom?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, hamiltonian, hydrogen

I tried using spherical coordinates, the wavefunction for the hydrogen atom and the Laplacian in spherical coordinates but I just ended up with a very long integral and I don't know what to do next. I don't know how to write math formulas here to show what I got.

Comment: [Here's a tutorial on how to use MathJaX to write equations](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on StackExchange sites.

Comment: Also, you might want to look at the virial theorem.  It is often stated in terms of time-averages in classical physics, but it also holds for expectation values in quantum-mechanical systems.  It would allow you to short-circuit the whole business of doing integrals.

Comment: There is no "the" wavefunction of the hydrogen atom, perhaps you mean the ground state? Anyway, if the state in question is an eigenstate of the Hamiltonian, you may be able to use the identity $\langle P^2/2m\rangle = E - \langle V\rangle$ (where $E$ is the energy of the eigenstate and $V$ is the potential) to avoid the Laplacian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $P^2 = 2 m T$, the easiest way would probably be to use the [Virial theorem](https://web1.eng.famu.fsu.edu/%7Edommelen/quantum/style_a/nt_virial.html) (as also mentioned by Micheal Seifert n the comments):

\begin{align}
\langle T\rangle =  \langle \mathbf{x}\cdot \boldsymbol{\nabla}V(\mathbf{x})\rangle/2
\end{align}
For the hydrogen atom, this actually simplifies rather nicely. Since $V(\mathbf{x}) \propto 1/r $, we have $\mathbf{x}\cdot \boldsymbol{\nabla}V(\mathbf{x}) = r ~\partial V(\mathbf{x})/\partial r = -V(\mathbf{x})$. So,
\begin{align}
\langle T\rangle = - \langle V(\mathbf{x})\rangle/2, \qquad (*)
\end{align}
since the total Hamiltonian is $H = T+V$, this means $\langle T \rangle = - \langle H\rangle/2 + \langle T\rangle/2$. In other words:
\begin{align}
\langle P^2\rangle = 2 m \langle T\rangle = - 2m\langle H\rangle.
\end{align}
This is extremely convenient, since for energy eigenstates, there's no calculation needed whatsoever! You just say $\langle P^2\rangle = -2m E$, where $E$ is the energy level in question.

More generally, if you're concerned with an arbitrary state $\psi(\mathbf{x})$, you can just carry out the integral in $(*)$:
\begin{align}
\langle T \rangle &= - \frac{1}{2} \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} d^3\mathbf{x} ~ \vert \psi(\mathbf{x})\vert^2 V(\mathbf{x})\\[5pt]
&=  \frac{e^2}{8\pi \epsilon_0} \int_0^{2\pi} d\varphi\int_0^{\pi} d\theta \int_0^{\infty} dr~r \sin\theta ~ \vert \psi(r,\theta,\varphi)\vert^2.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

As suggested above, you could use the virial theorem. Then I would suggest you to use the Hellman-Feynman theorem if you want to avoid performing any integral at all :)